# Are there any modern standards for building HTML5 applications with a build program?

Tags: html, makefile

For example, jQuery Mobile uses Make to assemble their various js and css files into a single js and css file.

The idea is to separate parts of the file that will ultimately be built into smaller files that are responsible for their own thing.

You can do the same thing with a webpage. Add in images as Base64 strings and you can have an entire website as a single .htm file but all of the files which make up that built file exist independently of one another, like normal. The image below might drive home the concept a little better.

[image]

I made my own program to do this which you can read about [here](http://www.dateequalsnull.com/apps/Builder/builderpropaganda.htm) if you want. My question is if anyone else has caught onto this idea or if there is a more standard way of doing this?

Comment: This concept means also there is nothing to cache (reload would overwrite allready loaded images complete) which makes such produced pages just interesting for content who changes every visit. in larger scale this is more complicated than in the `standard` way

Comment: I never said it could not be designed to accomadate those things. In fact, it can accomadate them as well as any other app. It's not just about eveything in one file although that is one case that is interesting. It's a bit about modularized reusable maintainable code

Comment: This sounds a lot like what MoveableType can do, with its static publishing mode, where it would render the html for all of the pages in the CMS. However, you may also be talking about idea of the HTML Application Cache, which allows you to bundle the files needed to run an app locally. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few that can be made to do that, like:

- [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)
- [Assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what Assemble was created to do. And Assemble is just a Grunt.js plugin

Answer (score 2):

We use [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) but have experimented with Grunt as a build tool.  Your flavor preference should determine what tool you run with:  Grunt is node.js based, rake ('ruby make') is Ruby based, and one of the common python build tools is [scons](http://www.scons.org/). Build tools are particularly handy for compiling SASS, performing css and js minification, and generating sprite images.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing I would call a "standard" (not even a defacto one) but there are some language specific options. I use the Coldfusion language with Railo and a contributed extension called [cfstylesheet/cfjavascript](http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/beta-railo-extensions-cfjavascript-cfstylesheet). It performs minification, merging and/or obsfucation on-the-fly (with caching) so you just setup your page with some extra tags as so:

```
<cfset src = ['/cfjs/test/js/A.js','/cfjs/test/js/B.js'] />
<cfjavascript src="#src#" path="/cfjs/test/jscompressed" filename="myJs"/>
```

PHP has a similar tool available called [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) that works in a similiar way.

A more generic tool is [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) which could be integrated into almost any build system as a batch script.